# How to handle Google Services API checkings for Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: android, firebase, google-api, firebase-cloud-messaging

I can't seem to find a way to make the Google Services API checkings work correctly for FCM.

The use case is the following:

The Google Play services app is disabled (*In emulator: Settings>apps>Google Play Services>Disabled*). The application starts. It runs the check and sees Google Play Services is disabled. As it is a `userResovlableError`, it calls the `getErrorDialog` which in turn shows the Google Play Services config screen to enable the services.

If the user **cancels** at any moment, it is fine, the app sends a toast and finishes. If the user **enables** the Google Play Services and hits back from the configuration screen, it is captured by the app in the `onActivityResult`.

***Note***: Most postings say that result should be `Activity.RESULT_OK`. This turned out to be wrong, so instead of checking the result status, I re-query the `GoogleApiAvailability` instance to see if it is now enabled.

After checking that the services are enabled, my assumption was that everything should be fine. But messages sent from the FCM server just don't reach the app.

My impression is that, as the app is executing from `onResume` after enabling the Google Apps Services, the registration of the device with the FCM server is not happening.

To overcome this, I thought of deleting the `FirebaseInstanceId` which seems to be something that should reset everything. The `deleteInstanceId` method has to be called from a different thread than the main one.

I have tried both, calling this method in a Runnable from a separate Thread, and the current approach of starting a ServiceIntent to do the deleting. In both cases, I get an `NullPointer` exception that crashes the Google Services App.

My code is posted below. Any idea on what could be the problem? Or is there any other working solution to correctly do this checking and error handling?

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;



public class MainTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1972;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_test);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }


    private boolean hasGooglePlayServices() {

        boolean rtn = false;
        GoogleApiAvailability instance = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int apiStatus = instance.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (apiStatus != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (instance.isUserResolvableError(apiStatus)) {
                instance.getErrorDialog(this, apiStatus, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST, new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        finishNotSupported();
                    }
                }).show();
                rtn = true;
            }else {
                rtn = false;
            }
        }else{
            rtn =  true;
        }
        return rtn;
    }




    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!hasGooglePlayServices()) {
            finishNotSupported();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST){

            int apiStatus = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
            if (apiStatus != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
                finishNotSupported();
            }else{
                Intent i = new Intent(this, DeleteTokenService.class);
                this.startService(i);
            }
        }
    }

    private void finishNotSupported(){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Esta app no está soportada por este dispositivo.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

This is the service doing the delete:

```
public class DeleteTokenService extends IntentService {

    public static final String TAG = DeleteTokenService.class.getSimpleName();


    public DeleteTokenService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
            FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        }catch(IOException e){
            Log.e(TAG,"Exceptin resetting token.",e);

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e(TAG,"Exceptin resetting token.",e);
        }
    }
}
```

There are two exceptions, the first one is the one crashing Google Services App. The second one is just the timeout because it never recieves a new FirebaseInstanceId.

This is the Stacktrace:

```
12326-12494/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                   Process: com.google.android.gms.persistent, PID: 12326
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                                                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.os.Messenger.send(android.os.Message)' on a null object reference
                                                       at opu.a(:com.google.android.gms:594)
                                                       at oom.doInBackground(:com.google.android.gms:3481)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                       at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
10-06 11:38:05.355 12269-12429/? E/DeleteTokenService: Exceptin resetting token.
                                                       java.io.IOException: TIMEOUT
                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzf.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.deleteInstanceId(Unknown Source)
                                                           at com.xxxxxxxxxxx.androidtestapp.DeleteTokenService.onHandleIntent(DeleteTokenService.java:28)
                                                           at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```